# What are the equivalent predicate logic inference rules?

Tags: logic

In propositional logic we had studied the following rules:

```
(P • Q)   ->  P, Q   
~(P ∨ Q)  ->  ~P, ~Q   
~(P ⊃ Q)  -> P, ~Q
```

and say, the inference rules:

```
~(P • Q), P -> ~Q
(P ∨ Q), ~P -> Q
(P ⊃ Q), ~Q -> ~P
```

Now in predicate logic you can use these rules but my question is how do I decide where does the negation go? This is unfortunately not clearly stated in the book.

For example:

If I have:

```
~((x)Pa ⊃ (x)Qa)
```

I can deduce two inferences from this such as firstly:

```
(x)Pa
```

But for the second inference where does the negation go?

Is it `(x)~Qa` or `~(x)Qa` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**¬(P → Q)** is equivalent to : **P ∧ ¬Q**.

Thus, **¬((x)Px → (x)Qx)** must be : **(x)Px ∧ ¬(x)Qx**.

Comment: Is it true in all the cases that the negation always goes before the quantifier? I am confused about where does the negation of this `(x)~Qa` comes from if the negation of `(x)(Qx)` is `~(x)Qx`?

Comment: @cpx - It depends on what your are expressing : "not all men are Greeks" is **¬(x)Qx** (that is true) and it is different from "all men are not-Greeks", i.e. **(x)¬Qx** (that is false).

Comment: I see. So, I guess that particular case is not actually a negation of something but rather an expression itself. In other words, all the negations should go in the front of quantifier if it is of something else, right?

Comment: @cpx - YES; the negation of an expression **A** is **always** **¬A**. Then, there are "equivalences", like those between **¬(x)Qx** and **(∃x)¬Qx** and between **(x)¬Qx** and **¬(∃x)Qx**.